# Tttach an object to the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, swiftui

I Ran into a problem - I can't attach text to the bottom of the screen - Text("**Общи условия и поверителност**")- when the screen is expanded a little, the object is at the bottom, but it doesn't change its location on large screens. I tried using Stack { space() item } but then the object just goes out of the screen's field of view. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Text("Общи условия и поверителност")

iphoneSE:

[image]

iphone11:
[image]

Comment: SwiftUI I assume (because you said `Stack { space() item }`)? Or Auto Layout/frames?

Comment: @aheze i menia Stack

Answer (score 0):

Try to position the screen with `.position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)`

You can use this extension for cleaner code -

```
extension UIScreen {
   static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
   static let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
   static let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
}
```

If you want to be more accurate you can GeometryReader like so -

```
GeometryReader { geo in 
   Text("Общи условия и поверителност")
       .potision(x: UIScreen.screenHeight - geo.safeAreaInsets.top)
}
```

This will also includes the safeArea in the calculations

Answer (score 0):

> Try to position the screen with .position(x:
> UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
>
> You can use this extension for cleaner code -
>
> extension UIScreen {    static let screenWidth =
> UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width    static let screenHeight =
> UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height    static let screenSize =
> UIScreen.main.bounds.size } If you want to be more accurate you can
> GeometryReader like so -
>
> GeometryReader { geo in     Text("Общи условия и поверителност")
> .potision(x: UIScreen.screenHeight - geo.safeAreaInsets.top) } This will also includes the safeArea in the calculations

@AvivProfesorsky -
[image]

The object has disappeared, but you can still click on it and go to another screen
o_O